# How to remove donut chart borders

Tags: r

[image]I would like to remove the border lines that separate colors on my donut chart. Is this possible?

```
df <- data.frame(
group = c("Never", "Only a \n few times", "Weekly", "Daily", "Multiple \n times per day"),
value = c(5,28, 34, 27, 6))

par(mar=c(5, 10, 5, 5) )  # this sets margins to allow long labels
#par(oma=c(0,0,0,0))
# create labels
df$label <- paste(df$group,
              scales::percent(df$value/sum(df$value), accuracy = 1), sep = "\n")

ggpubr::ggdonutchart(df, "value",
                 label = "label", # add labels
                 color = "white",fill = "group",
                 lab.pos = c("out"), #THIS PLACES DATA LABELS ON OUTSIDE OF DONUT
                 lab.adjust = 1,
                 radius = .3,
                 borders ='n',
                 palette = c("dodgerblue3", "darkorange2", "lightsteelblue4", "goldenrod1", 
"dodgerblue4")) +
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]theme(legend.position = "none") #DELETES LEGEND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to remove these borders, you can do `color = NULL`.

```
ggpubr::ggdonutchart(df, "value",
                     label = "label", # add labels
                     color = NULL,fill = "group",
                     lab.pos = c("out"), #THIS PLACES DATA LABELS ON OUTSIDE OF DONUT
                     lab.adjust = 1,
                     radius = .3,
                     borders ='n',
                     palette = c("dodgerblue3", "darkorange2", "lightsteelblue4", "goldenrod1", 
                                 "dodgerblue4"))
```

[image]

And here is another tip you might find useful, if you do not want to remove borders but just make them look like the fill color AND keep a nice legend, you can do `color = "group"` and `fill = "group"`

```
ggpubr::ggdonutchart(df, "value",
                     label = "label", # add labels
                     color = "group",fill = "group",
                     lab.pos = c("out"), #THIS PLACES DATA LABELS ON OUTSIDE OF DONUT
                     lab.adjust = 1,
                     radius = .3,
                     borders ='n',
                     palette = c("dodgerblue3", "darkorange2", "lightsteelblue4", "goldenrod1", 
                                 "dodgerblue4"))
```

[image]